# How to write a menu driven python program that works with an address book? Pydev

Tags: python, menu, pydev, user-defined-functions

```
def write():
    writefile=input("Please enter the last name: ")
    name=input("Please enter your name:")
    street=input("Enter House Number and Street Name:")
    city=input('Enter City, State and ZIP:')
    home=input('Enter Home Phone Number:')
    mobile=input('Enter Cell Phone Number:')
    outfile=open('C:\\Users\\Force\workspace\addressbook.txt','w')
    outfile.write("Added "+name+writefile)
    outfile.write(street+city+home+mobile)
    outfile.close()
def read():
    phonebook=open("C:\\Users\\Force\workspace\addressbook.txt",'r')
    numEntries=0
    lastName=phonebook.readline().rstrip()
    while lastName!='':
        firstName=phonebook.readline().rstrip()
        street=phonebook.readline().rstrip()
        city=phonebook.readline().rstrip()
        homephone=phonebook.readline().rstrip()
        mobilephone=phonebook.readline().rstrip()
        numEntries=numEntries+1
        LastName=phonebook.readline().rstrip()
def menu():
    print('1: Look up person by last name')
    print('2: Add a person to the address book')
    print('3: Quit')
    option=input('Pick your option: ')
    if option==1:
        read()
    if option==2:
        write()
    if option==3:
        print("Good bye!")
menu()
```

Every time it brings me to the menu and I try selecting an option it just terminates the program. Not sure if it's my user defined functions, the opening of the text file or even just all of it. (Using Pydev 3.6)

Answer (score 1):

In `option=input('Pick your option: ')`, option is a string. You could either convert it to an int, or test it with

```
if option=='1':
```

And - not to be picky, but you might want to consider 'elif'

Comment: Oh ha thanks! And yeah it's a bad habit that I keep forgetting about. Keeping that in mind there.